# What is the most common way to create a folder selection dialog using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, folderbrowserdialog, topendialog

There doesn't appear to be a simple component available to create a folder selection dialog in Delphi 2009, although a file selection dialog is provided by way of the TOpenDialog.

What is the most common way to create a modern folder selection dialog using Delphi?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two overloaded routines in FileCtrl.pas called SelectDirectory

For a modern look, use the second form, with sdNewUI

```
var
  dir : string;
begin
  dir := 'C:\temp';
  FileCtrl.SelectDirectory('Select', 'C:\', dir, [sdNewFolder, sdNewUI], Self);
end;
```

NOTE: sdNewFolder, sdNewUI etc are only available from D2006+

Comment: Thanks for that. I did look at SelectDirectory previously but I didn't see the option for the modern UI.

Comment: A list of the available options in the Options parameter for SelectDirectory can be found here: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/FileCtrl_TSelectDirExtOpt.html

Comment: Using FileCtrl.pas gives me a warning: Unit "FileCtrl" is specific to a platform. Is there a solution without this unit?

Answer (score 2):

you can use SelectDirectory from FileCtrl unit

```
using FileCtrl;
var
  St: string;
begin
  St:='c:\';
  if SelectDirectory(St,[],0) then 
  begin
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download a component [PBFolderDialog](http://bak-o-soft.dk/Delphi/PBFolderDialog.aspx)  from "http://bak-o-soft.dk/Delphi/PBFolderDialog.aspx" which is quite easy to use and offers access to all options of the Windows "SHBrowseForFolder" dialog; something which the built-in ones not do.

It's freeware with source and not too difficult to port to Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 0):

See the sample code:

---

Delphi tip#157: select folder dialog
http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0157.htm

---